# Using Regex in Java to "transform" a css style in html tag style

Tags: java, html, css, regex

I have a HTML code stored in a String variable in a Java code, in this string I have something like this:

```
<span style="text-decoration: underline;">test</span>
```

And I want something like this

```
<u>test</u>
```

Or if I have this:

```
<span style="color: #2873ee; text-decoration: underline;">test</span>
```

I want this:

```
<font color="#2873ee"><u>test</u></font>
```

Using regex I can do this:

```
affectedString.replaceAll("<span style=\"text-decoration: underline;\">(.*?)<\\/span>", "<u>$1</u>");
```

and

```
affectedString.replaceAll("<span style=\"color:\\s*?(#[A-Fa-f0-9]{6}|[A-Fa-f0-9]{3}); text-decoration: underline;\">(.*?)<\\/span>", "<u><font color=\"$1\">$2</u></font>");
```

Easy right? But I have a few issues and also I don't like this code.
First, why I don't like this? because I need to use this in css style of: Underline, Color and Line-through, and write every case of coincidence is not a good code, for example:

```
affectedString.replaceAll("<span style=\"color:\\s*?(#[A-Fa-f0-9]{6}|[A-Fa-f0-9]{3}); text-decoration: underline;\">(.*?)<\\/span>", "<u><font color=\"$1\">$2</u></font>");
affectedString.replaceAll("<span style=\"text-decoration: underline; color:\\s*?(#[A-Fa-f0-9]{6}|[A-Fa-f0-9]{3});\">(.*?)<\\/span>", "<u><font color=\"$2\">$1</u></font>");
```

And the issues is this don't work with a code like:

```
<span style="text-decoration: underline;">test <span style="text-decoration: line-through;">two</span></span>
```

In that case when I try to apply the regex, the portion matches until the first `</span>`, so the final result is:

```
<u>test<span style="text-decoration:line-through;">two</u></span>
```

This is when I match the text-decoration:underline, then when I match the text-decoration:line-through. The second result is:

```
<u>test <strike>two</u></strike>
```

When the expected result is

```
<u>test <strike>two</strike></u>
```

My questions are, what regex I can use to solve this type of issues? And there is a better solution to "transform" that simple css into the html tags?

Thanks

Comment: You should not use Regex to parse the XML/HTML.

Comment: Any regex you or some other answerer offers for such task will be complicated, bug-prone and ugly looking. You definetly need some kind of html analyzer/parser for this

Answer (score 1):

I'd advise against using regex. It isn't easy to debug/extend and gets nasty pretty fast. You could use a library like [jsoup](http://jsoup.org) to parse the HTML, traverse the DOM and use CSS selectors to get Elements. E.g. to get all divs with a `class` attribute you'd use

`Elements divs = doc.select("div[class]");`